# Ajax reload content when back button selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hi I have seen other posts like this but nothing exactly the same.  I have an ajax site that I am trying to develope and I cant get the content to reload when the back button is clicked.  I am currently using Dynamic Drives ajax content script.  Then I have a script that changes the url onclick and have a popstate script to enable the back button.  My problem is that I cant get the content that was previously in the div to reload.  Im not sure how to do this.  I have seen posts that have a reload of the hash value but through the script that I am using the links are javascript so there is no hash fired.  Then I have an onlick event that replaces the url with the page url that I am linking to.  All of this works fine but when you hit back and forward the conent remains the same.  I need it to reload the conent that was originally there.  I got this code below from some posts on this site and they work fine but cant get the content reloaded with the back button.  Hopefully there is someone who can help with this it has been driving me crazy.

```
function updateHistory(){
var state = {
  "CanBeAnything": true
};
history.pushState(state, "Title", "/page.html");
expect(history.state).toEqual(state);}



$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
    $.ajax({url:location.pathname+'&rel=tab',success: function(data){
        $('#page-load-area').html(data);
    }});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show us the php script on the server  maybe you need to unset($_GET)

Comment: So I found out that for some reason when you first enter the page the browser doesn't register that because there is nothing loaded after the domain name.  I acutually found a script from css tricks http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content that works a lot better and allows for search engines to crawl and for non javascript users to still use the site.  Then placed a script to place a hash value when the index loads.